# Webpack css setup and best practise

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I am new to webpack and would like to use it with reactjs but kind of lost confused right now. I would like to know how css is handled in the client site development process with webpack. I know that webpack bundles all my js and links it as bundle.js which I reference in my html file like this:`<script src="http://localhost:3000/assets/bundle.js"></script>` based on my configuration of webpack-dev-server.
Now, I do have also a css file. Where does this go? what would be my url to reference this in my html file.
I understand that there is a style-loader and a css-loader and also an ExtractTextPlugin, but where does the output belong? I saw that I can `var css = require('path/customStyle.css')` but dos not seems to see where it appears? I do this in my index.jsx file.
So the question his: How to get this together, that I can reference my customStyle.css. What do I do wrong, or what do I miss 
Here is my project folder structure:

```
|_source
|   |_js
|       |_js
|       |    |_components
|       |      |_ *.jsx
|       |_index.jsx
|_assets
|  |_css
|    |_customStyle.css
|__index.html
```

My webpack.config.js looks like this

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './source/js/index.jsx',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8090/assets'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                loader: 'jsx-loader?insertPragma=React.DOM&harmony'
            },
            {
              test: /\.css$/,
              loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader","css-loader")
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {

        'react': 'React'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx','.css']
    },
    plugins:[
      new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
    ]
}
```

Html file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="../node_modules/react/dist/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<!-- like to link css here but don't know the path to link to -->
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">

  </div>
  <script src="http://localhost:3000/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
  <script src="http://localhost:3000/assets/bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help with some background on how the webpack way works and how to get my styles in would be fantastic.

Comment: It's 2yr old question and I guess you must have found the solution. If not then use `extract-text-webpack-plugin`, `css-loader`, `html-webpack-plugin` to organise the HTML, JSX, CSS files.

Answer (score 4):

Your css will be bundled together with the Javascript file. There is no seperate css file to link in your html. You can use the extract-text-webpack-plugin to create a separate css file for production.

Also you might want to avoid putting absolute urls in your html. Better use a template and have webpack inject the right script tags by using the html-webpack-plugin. This is what your template might look like (example taken from YARSK):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Yet Another React Starter Kit</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.{%=o.webpack.hash%}.css" media="all">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="{%=o.htmlWebpackPlugin.assets.main%}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I suggest to have a look at the [YARSK](http://bradleyboy.github.io/yarsk/) starter kit to see how it's done.

Answer (score 2):

[html-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin) can generate **index.html** for you. If you need something more custom, it allows you to customize the template it uses. I've found this plugin highly useful in practice.

I go into more detail at a [chapter](http://survivejs.com/webpack_react/building_kanban/) of mine. It shows how various bits connect to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to care that much about css with webpack. All it needs is that it finds them with require. More important is the way you organize them in your source folders. We had a large project and since with all the components it became quite scattered. We decided to place common style files to one place and then component specific under component folder.